# Site Registration & MailChimp Coordination?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, user-registration, plugin-mailchimp

I have a client who would like to post research documents on his site for download with the following functionality:

1. Users could browse entire site, but in order to download, users would need to register and login.
2. Would like all registration info to be automatically passed to MailChimp (name, email, other optional info) for inclusion into mailing list.
3. User would be able to opt out of mailings, but keep site registration active

Are there any existing plugins (or combo of plugins) that do this?

Answer (score 2):

Mailchimp has several WordPress plugin you can get directly from their site. Other mail services also provide WordPress specific plugins besides Mailchimp.

http://kb.mailchimp.com/connect

These plugins interface directly with WordPress signups or as a separate form, the Mailchimp signups by default need user confirmation and provide opt-out.

As for download only for members, it depends how you structure the downloads, you can have a members only download sections, or a manager for post links, etc.

For instance using:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/download-monitor/
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-members/
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/member-access/

Answer (score 0):

Points 1 and 2 can be easily solved with [Chimpy - MailChimp WordPress Plugin](http://codecanyon.net/item/chimpy-mailchimp-wordpress-plugin/6290216). It comes with user sync functionality - passes data to MailChimp when user is created, updated and deleted.

If you only wanted your visitors to subscribe in order to access content, this plugin would cover your scenario 100% (there's a functionality named "Subscribe To Unlock").

Wyck posted links to a few nice plugins for restricting access to some of your content.

*Disclosure: I'm the author of the aforementioned plugin.*